# backbone js add printing region dynamically

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a requirement to print the View model data using Print Button.

Currently i have a div and assigning my view content to it. This div has been already added in backbone region. In my javascript function, i am just setting the viewmodel content to the printdiv and it working with out any issue.

But the content which i have added for printing is getting appended in the browser HTML also, I dont want to show that in my browser. I tried setting visible hidden and display none to my printingdiv. but then printing is not working since the content is not visible

**CSHTML:**

```
<div id="printdiv"/>
```

**JS:**

```
  Myapp.printdiv.show(viewData.view);
  window.print();
```

**Init.JS**

```
Myapp.addRegions({
printdiv: '#printdiv',
});
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this sort of problem is with a print-specific stylesheet.  [This article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) explains how to do that in detail, but the short version is that you define your non-print styles as normal, then use CSS code like the following to override print-specific styles:

```
#printdiv {
    display: none
}

@media print {
    #printdiv {
        display: block;
    }
}
```